# How to remove rows with a duplicate entry when querying with peewee in flask?

Tags: python, peewee

I'm using flask, peewee, sqlite3. For a billing system, I'm trying to create an overview of all bills for a particular user. A new bill is added with a "bill_number" and can have multiple line items. If the bill has multiple line items, the "bill_number" will be duplicated in the database. When I query the database I, only want to get the first row that shows the "bill_number" and skip the other rows with the same "bill_number".

```
SQlite Database:
| id | bill_number | user_id | description |  price  |
| 1  | 1           | 8       | Logo Design |  250.00 |
| 2  | 2           | 8       | Web Design  |  500.00 |
| 3  | 2           | 8       | Logo Design |  250.00 |
| 4  | 3           | 8       | Web Design  |  550.00 |
| 5  | 4           | 8       | Img Design  |  250.00 |
```

In my app Id like to query with something like:

```
@app.route('/billOverview')
def bill_overview():
  bills = models.Bill.select().where(models.Bill.user_id == current_user.id).deduplicate(models.Bill.bill_number)
  return render_template('bills-overview.html', bills=bills)
```

So that I could easily read in my template like:

```
{% for bill in bills %}
 view details for <a href="">Bill #{{ bill.bill_number }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Rendered would look something like:

```
view details for Bill #1
view details for Bill #2
view details for Bill #3
view details for Bill #4
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved it myself. The answer was a lot easier than expected :-)

```
bills = models.Bill.select().where(models.Bill.user_id == current_user.id).group_by(models.Bill.bill_number)
```

I was looking for **group_by()**

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like peewee supports the API you mentioned.  You have a couple options:

- Use a group by to deduplicate on the bill_number column, see [this](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/hacks.html#top-object-per-group) "hack" in the peewee docs.
- Normalize your schema further.  Don't allow more than one `(bill_number, user_id)` row in this table.  Create another table (`bill_items` or something) to store each individual item.  This way, your `select` query will return the rows you want, and you can join the new table to get a detailed view.